# Convert a (varchar (64), null) into a numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column with a datatype of `VARCHAR (64),null`. The resulting figure is a percentage, ie...24%, 12%, etc... I need the figure to be in the format of .25, .12, etc...

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way you can do it:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
DECLARE @percentage VARCHAR(64) = '12%';

SELECT @percentage
    , CAST(REPLACE(@percentage, '%', '') AS INT)/100.0;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: you're welcome just accept the answer if you are happy with it :)